# What was the design decision to merge IplImage and cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV 2.0, they switched from having separate image and matrix classes to a unified class called `cv::Mat`. What was the design decision there? To me, who works with both images and matrices on a daily basis, they are very different objects that just happen to have a commonality: they are both accessed in a grid. However, the thing that makes a matrix a matrix in my mind is you can do `y = A*x`, where A is m by n, x is n by 1, and y is m by 1. This makes almost no sense when A is an image why you would want to do this operation.

Merging the classes also had the nasty side effect of needing templating and odd matrix types (like `CV_32FC3` for a 3-channel floating-point matrix/image). Since I know the guys working on OpenCV aren't crazy, what was the design decision that made them merge image and matrix classes? Was it code reuse? Was it efficiency somehow?

Comment: This is a question for the OpenCV mailing list where you can get the original developers to share what they know about such decision.

Answer (score 3):

Main drawback is that you can't overload ' * ' to do a multiplcation, but I don't think you should overload ' * ' for anything more complex than builtin types anyway.

What is a convolution kernel - an image or a matrix?

You only have to learn all the handler/ctor functions once - instead of two sets of them